# How to close connection with returned value in PyMySQL lib?

Tags: python, pymysql

I have the following code:

```
import pymysql.cursors
class MylocalSQL:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def get_max_report_date(self):
        connection = pymysql.connect(host=...,
                                     charset='utf8mb4',
                                     cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
        try:
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                # Read a single record
                sql = "SELECT value from tab limit 1 "
                cursor.execute(sql)
                result = cursor.fetchone()
                print(result)
        finally:
            connection.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mysql = MylocalSQL()
    mysql.get_max_report_date()
```

I want to change the `print(result)` into `return`  so i can do:

```
value = mysql.get_max_report_date()
```

However if I change the `print(result)` into `return result` then the finally block won't be executed.

Is there a better way to manage the connection & handling errors while being able to return the value from the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mistaken about the behavior of finally. The finally block is executed, even if you have the `return` statement.

```
class MylocalSQL:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def get_max_report_date(self):
        try:
            return "some value"
        finally:
            print('i was executed')


MylocalSQL().get_max_report_date()
```

prints "I was executed"

https://ideone.com/KhvVKy

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable before. Assign the result to your variable. Close the connection. Return the variable.